# C++ Code Snippet Execution

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, execution

I am working on a past exam paper, and I was wondering if anyone could explain the solution to this question: given this (incorrect) snippet of code being a header file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Weight
{
public:
    Weight(const int = 0, const int = 0);
    Weight(const int = 0);
    int totalPounds();
    Weight operator+(const Weight);
    Weight operator++();
    Weight operator++(int);
private:
    int stones;
    int pounds
};
void operator<<(ostream& os, const Weight&);
```

And this execution in a main method, and assuming a .cpp class exists with an implementation of said header file.

```
Weight a(12);
const Weight b(15, 3);
const int FIXED_WEIGHT = b.totalPounds();
Weight combined = a + b;
++a;
b++
combined = 5 + a;
a = b + 1;
cout << a << b;
```

Which of the lines would cause an error in regards to the header file and what modifications would need to be made to the header file?

I am really confused, we barely covered default params in class... I tried removing them which made the code work but I don't think that's the solution. Also what do the line of code `const int = 0` mean and how would I implement something based on that. Wouldn't this lead to ambiguously defined constructors?

Comment: const int =0 -> if no parameters are given, then default to 0. this makes the constructor with the single parameter redundant. so for "Weight a(12);", the program does not know which constructor to use.

Comment: The most obvious mistake is `using namespace std;` and the corresponding omission of `std::` in the declaration of `operator<<`.

Comment: shouldnt the compiler answer your question?

Comment: I mean, the compiler did, I probably did not word it but how would I provide an implementation keeping both constructors (otherwise the main method cannot execute its calls and I am not allowed to modify it though I believe the professor made an error in making the variable b const

Comment: He probably did it on purpose, wanting you to make the `operator++()` const, although it is very uncommon.

Comment: @A.S.H `b++` uses `operator++(int)`

Comment: @M.M Sure, but the idea is the same for both: any of them (prefix or postfix) may be declared as const and overloaded in a way that does not change the object's state. Although it looks extremely uncommon, this might be what the teacher wants... The only thing that looks "non-fixable" in `main` is the `5 + a` thing (and yet, probably feasible).

Comment: Hard to say what they want the behaviour of `++` on a const object to do.    The `5 + a` is easily fixable: add a non-member `operator+` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the missing `;` after `pounds` and `b++` are typos, the errors I see are:

1. Ambiguous constructors. You only need the first one.
2. `b` is const, so calling `totalPounds` fails as it is not a const method.
3. `b` is const, so post-increment fails since it is not a const method.
4. `5 + a` fails, since there is no matching `+` operator to use.
5. `b` is const, so `b + 1` fails since `+` is not a const method.
6. `void` return value for `operator<<` causes `cout` statement to fail.
7. `operator<<(ostream& os, const Weight&)` is not a friend, so no way to actually print internal values of `Weight`.

Comment: regarding `7`, it'd be OK if it only output `totalPounds`  (and if that method were `const` of course)

Comment: @M.M: Ah, that's true.

Comment: Thank you, this caught everything that I didn't catch!